# JavaScript not further executed once a button is disabled

Tags: javascript, button

I am using next and prev buttons so one question will be shown at a time, however, once next or prev buttons are disabled, the other button doesn't work anymore either. Here's my code:

```js
var showing = [1, 0, 0, 0];
var questions = ['q0', 'q1', 'q2', 'q3'];

function next() {
  var qElems = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    qElems.push(document.getElementById(questions[i]));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i <= showing.length; i++) {
    if (showing[i] == 1) {
      showing[i] = 0;
      if (i == showing.length - 1) {
        document.getElementById("next").disabled = true;
      } else {
        console.log(i);
        qElems[i + 1].style.display = 'block';
        qElems[i].style.display = 'none';
        showing[i + 1] = 1;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}

function prev() {
  var qElems = [];
  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    qElems.push(document.getElementById(questions[i]));
  }
  for (var i = 0; i <= showing.length; i++) {
    if (showing[i] == 1) {
      showing[i] = 0;
      if (i == showing.length - 4) {
        document.getElementById("prev").disabled = true;
      } else {
        qElems[i - 1].style.display = 'block';
        qElems[i].style.display = 'none';
        showing[i - 1] = 1;
      }
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you recreate the issue in a fiddle?

Comment: I made you a snippet. Please add relevant HTML to it

Comment: Also DRY - don't repeat yourself. Use the ID to get the direction you need

Comment: Sorry I am not sure how to add html to the snippet. I am not able to figure out how to edit my question. Can you guys help? meanwhile i'll try to recreate in JSFiddle

Comment: Click edit, then scroll down and click "edit above snippet"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want this simplified script

I had to guess the HTML, but there is only one function.

```js
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  let showing = 0;
  const questions = document.querySelectorAll(".q");
  questions[showing].style.display = "block";
  const next = document.getElementById("next");
  const prev = document.getElementById("prev");
  document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
    var but = e.target, dir;

         if (but.id === "prev") dir = -1;
    else if (but.id === "next") dir =  1;
    else return; // not a button

    questions[showing].style.display = "none"; // hide current
    showing += dir; // up or down
    next.disabled = showing === questions.length-1;
    if (showing <= 0) showing = 0;
    prev.disabled = showing === 0 
    questions[showing].style.display = "block";
  })
})
```

```css
.q { display:none }
```

```html
<div class="q" id="q0">Question 0</div>
<hr/>
<div class="q" id="q1">Question 1</div>
<hr/>
<div class="q" id="q2">Question 2</div>
<hr/>
<div class="q" id="q3">Question 3</div>
<hr/>
<div id="nav">
  <button type="button" id="prev" disabled>Prev</button>
  <button type="button" id="next">Next</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Since this is a quiet interesting java script task, Im doing my own solution.

Hope this matches the requirement.

I have created 4 divs of which first one is only displayed at first. Remaining divs are placed hidden. On clicking next, the divs are displayed according to index. Once the last and first indexes are interpreted, the respective next and previous buttons are enabled and disabled.

```js
var showing = [1, 0, 0, 0];
var questions = ['q0', 'q1', 'q2', 'q3'];
var qElems = [];

function initialize() {
  for (var i = 0; i < questions.length; i++) {
    qElems.push(document.getElementById(questions[i]));
  }
}

function updatevisibilitystatus(showindex, hideindex) {
  qElems[showindex].style.display = 'block';
  qElems[hideindex].style.display = 'none';
  showing[showindex] = 1;
}

function next() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= showing.length; i++) {
    if (showing[i] == 1) {
      showing[i] = 0;
      if (i == showing.length - 2) {
        document.getElementById("next").disabled = true;
      } 
      updatevisibilitystatus(i + 1, i);
      document.getElementById("prev").disabled = false;
      break;
    }
  }
}

function prev() {
  for (var i = 0; i <= showing.length; i++) {
    if (showing[i] == 1) {
      showing[i] = 0;
      if (i == 1) {
        document.getElementById("prev").disabled = true;
      } 
      updatevisibilitystatus(i - 1, i);
      document.getElementById("next").disabled = false;
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<body onload="initialize()">
  <div id="q0" style="display: block;">Q0</div>
  <div id="q1" style="display: none;">Q1</div>
  <div id="q2" style="display: none;">Q2</div>
  <div id="q3" style="display: none;">Q3</div>
  <button id="prev" disabled onclick="prev()">Prev</button>
  <button id="next" onclick="next()">Next</button>
</body>
```

Comment: This is perfect Nitheesh. Thank you so much

Comment: It is not actually perfect. It is STILL not using DRY - the code looping is highly inelegant.